# How can I adjust ContourPlot in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, image, plotting, code-generation

I have problem because of the max point and min point, when I have too high or low data point, it just make it white.

Here is example of data

```
Data = Table[
   1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + Cos[x*y] - 
    1/Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2], {x, -3.01, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3.01, 
    3, 0.1}];
```

and I listplot this

```
ListContourPlot[Data, ContourLabels -> False, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

and I got

[image]

I do not like this graph because the white area does not tell me it is max or min, so I adjust the code to fix the max and min as the certain color

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
plTest = ListContourPlot[Data, 
   Contours -> {-5, -2.5, -1, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 5}, 
   ImageSize -> 720, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 60}, {0, 60}, All}];
ShowLegend[plTest, {ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][1 - #1] &, 30, "max",
   "min", LegendPosition -> {0.7, 0.15}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}}]
```

and I got

[image]

but Now I cannot see all the interesting things in the interval that all the small values are in.

Is there any way that I can fix the color of certain interval that max and min points are in and plot contour on just certain range?

Comment: What version are you using? `ShowLegend` was made obsolete in v9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `ClippingStyle->Automatic`

```
data = Table[
   1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + Cos[x*y] -
    1/Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2],
   {x, -3.01, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3.01, 3, 0.1}];

ListContourPlot[data,
 ContourLabels -> Automatic,
 Contours -> 20,
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]